# how to do make a drop function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am having some problems with a jquery drag and drop div. At this moment I have the following jquery code:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function() { 
                    $('#coursesList').click(function() {
                        $('#dragCourseFromArea').hide(); 
                        $('#dragCourse').fadeIn(1100);              
                            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                            $('#dragCourse').text(selectedValue);


                    }); 

                    $('#dragCourse').draggable({ revert: true });
                    $('#calendarDay').droppable({ 
                tolerance: 'touch',
                            accept: '#dragCourse',
                            activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
                              hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
                              drop: function( event, ui ) {
                                $( this )
                                  .addClass( 'ui-state-highlight' )
                                  .find('td')
                                    .html( 'Dropped!' );
                        }
                    });
                });             
                </script>
```

I am not sure if this is where the problem is. The 3 concerning elements is these:

```
<div id='dragCourseFromArea'>Drag new courses from this box to allocate</div>
<div id='dragCourse' class='ui-widget-content'></div>

<td id='calendarDay' style='background-color: #E4E4EE;' onMouseOver='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#cccccc\"' onMouseOut='this.style.backgroundColor=\"#E4E4EE\"' class='ui-widget-header'> {$monthday}</td>
```

I am not completely sure if I have done this right, but the "dragcourse" div is the one that should be dragged and dropped on the "calendarDay" which is a table cell (td). But no matter what I change, I can't seem to get this to work. Any suggestions on what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net with what you have now, and explanation of what needs to happen

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ackV5/ I don't know why the jquery wont run here, but you can see the code. Andwhat needs to happen is that the element/div "dragcourse" should be able to be dragged onto td (cell) "calendarDay", which again should execute an action.

Comment: reason jQUery wasn't working is you didn't include it in `Frameworks` selection in top left of Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is you can't repeat ID's in  page, by definition an ID is unique. I updated your demo with a hack that adds class `calandarDay` to each of the same ID.

Then apply `droppable` to the class and it works up to the point of changing the html to `Dropped!`.

Note that the `"this"` within the drop callback is the `<td>` so I commented out `find('td')`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ackV5/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Great! Now That works, I have a another question:
Is it possible to get a value from the droppable, when the draggable is dropped? E.g. get a value from a input=hidden field in the td? Also when this happens, call another function where the value from the draggable (the name) and from the droppable (the hidden field) is passed to. I hope this isn't a too broad question. Really appreciate your help btw!

Comment: of course you can. Inspct the `ui` object that's logged to console. Will see a significant number of properties, including how to connect what element was dropped. Use other events from draggable docs to initalize data you need. Look into `jQuery.data() rather than hidden fields

Comment: I looked into it and changed some of my jquery to this:
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui)
        var ts = $('.calendarDayTimestamp').data('options').timestamp;
              $( this )
                 .addClass( 'ui-state-highlight' )
                  .append(ts+'<br>' ); 
         $('#dragCourse').fadeOut(800);  
         $('#dragCourseArea').fadeIn(800);   
              }

Do you think something is wrong here or is it another place?
When I drop it on a td cell it just writes the same value no matter where it is ...

Comment: you can't reference the whole class of `calendarDay` like that, you need the specific one.

Comment: stop and think about what `"this" is. Using class to look for something you already have. Then look close at the Ui object in console...can see reference to what's dropped

Comment: hmm but how do I do that when im generating the div with id=calendarDayTimestamp in a php loop ? :/ im just thought I could do the same as with my calendarDay id.. so I tried:
 $('[id=calendarDayTimestamp]').addClass('calendarDayTimestamp');
which obviously didn't work out ..

Comment: `$('[id=calendarDayTimestamp]')` needs to be removed, that's why i noted it as a hack, you need to change all those ID to class in markup...ID's must be unique!! Not sure what issue is with the `timestamp` is

Comment: can use `data-` attributes for all the existing events in the markup...will be read by `jQuery.data()`

Comment: if I was you would look at `fullcalendar` plugin...has an awesome API. Also...far easier working with json and javascript than worrying about inserting in html data server side . Why try to make the interface work in 2 environments? User is working client side, do all your data manipultion there also, just provide html from server

Comment: Well, the issue is that the timestamp always is the same when I drop over one of the td elements. So im thinking if this is right:
 <div class="calendarDayTimestamp" data-options="{'timestamp':''.$currentTimestamp}.''}"></div>
Which is located in each td generated by the php loop.. The $currentTimestamp is different every time the loop is runned through, but still the same timestaamp is fetched when I drop th draggable on the td.. I really hope you understand this and maybe have some kind of solution:P

Comment: not sure what you are using timestamp for...create demo with live html

Comment: the timestamp represents the current date in the calendar.. but sure I can make a live demo. just a sec

Comment: ahh yes..I get it, not sure whay you added the new class....but if `data-` attribute is on td will be accesible from `this` in drop'

Comment: Ahhh bingo! It's working now ;) thanks a lot, u have been a great help

Comment: problem you had was looking at every `.clandarDayTimestamp` in the page, have to isolate....so could have done `var DayCell=$(this);
                                  var TimeSTampDiv=DayCell.find('.calendarDayTimestamp')`

Comment: I have updated the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Jzh/1/ . If anyone should run into a simular problem